# Popup using InputBindings hides on mouse up

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup, contextmenu

I'm coding a MVVM library which allows to show a custom context menu with customizable DataTemplates. It's been tested and working well if I show it from a command (in a Button ,for example), but now I'm trying to show it using InputBindings to catch MouseGestures so I can easily bind it to a right mouse button click.

The code is written as follows:

```
<DataGrid Margin="274,10,10,10" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ModulosVM.TablasList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ModulosVM.TablaSelected}" Grid.Column="1" MouseUp="DataGrid_MouseUp">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Header=""/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TableName}" Header="Tabla"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding ShowTableMenuCommand}"></MouseBinding>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that when I right click one of the rows of the DataGrid the menu begins the showing animation but it hides if I release the mouse button before the animation completes. If I keep the button pressed until animation finishes, then I can use it normally and behaves as expected.

ShowTableMenuCommand works fine if I call it from a Button, showing the context menu with the expected behavior of a typical right click context menu (shows on right click, hides on menu item clicking).

What I'd like to achieve is to make the full menu showing animation even if I release the mouse button.

For more info, what the Command does is triggering an event that the window catches and runs the popup generation and showing:

```
        Popup popupMenu = new Popup();
        popupMenu.StaysOpen = false;
        popupMenu.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.None;
        popupMenu.PlacementTarget = w;
        popupMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse;
        popupMenu.Closed += (o, e) =>
        {
            popupMenu.IsOpen = false;
            vm.Dispose();
        };

        popupMenu.Child = new PopupMenuPanel(vm);
        popupMenu.AllowsTransparency = true;
        popupMenu.DataContext = vm;
        popupMenu.IsOpen = true;

        return popupMenu;
```

Where PopupMenuPanel is a custom control with all the customization settings. I've tried with different popup animations and all of them show this behavior. In fact, PopupAnimation.None hides the menu unless I go over it before releasing the button. After that the menu keeps open even if I "Mouse Leave" it.

Any word on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `MouseUp="DataGrid_MouseUp"` doing (i.e. the code) and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Actually it's a test method and it's empty, sorry.